# Mapfish toolbar issue while using ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, openlayers, extjs3

We are using Mapfish Toolbar with ExtJS3 in our application.Now we are trying to migrate our application to ExtJS4.But we are facing an issue with Mapfish toolbar.So,we tried with ExtJS4 toolbar,but the openlayers code related to map is not working with ExtJS4 toolbar.

So,Is there any chance to get ExtJS4 support mapfish toolbar or else any chance to work out the openlayers code with ExtJS4 toolbar?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help unless your post you code the error messages you are getting after migration to ExtJS 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapfish doesn’t ship with a javascript part anymore. There won’t be support for ExtJs4, you should use GeoExt instead.

http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/widgets/Action.html

HTH,